# How to set attributes of an instance through a dictionary with a for loop (python)

Tags: python, class, dictionary, iterable

I am trying to add attributes to this class through a dictionary. I have a dictionary (dict) which follows this order

```
{'Subject' + str(number) : subject introduced previously}
```

for instance,

```
{'Subject0' : 'Chemistry'}
```

So i'm trying to implement this on a class as it follows:

```py
class Subjects:

    def __init__(self, name, dictVar, yearCourse):
        self.name = name
        self.dictVar = dictVar
        self.yearCourse = yearCourse
        self.label = self.name [0:3] + self.yearCourse

    def getLabel(self):
        print (self.label)

for key, value in dict.items:
    key = Subjects(value, key, yearCourse)
```

The original code has the corresponding identation, it is a formating mistake

I took the dict.items from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

If I run

```
Subject0.getLabel()
```

Nothing happens, since I apparently have an error in the for loop

```
for key, value in dict.items:
```

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Thank you good human being if you have read this whole bible :)

Comment: You need to call `dict.items`, eg change your for loop to `for key, value in dict.items():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change `dict.items` to `dict.items()`.